# The Datediff and YYYYMM conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Can anyone help correct me for below conversions from `SQL server` to `Oracle`?

1. I only need month value 'MM' from below substraction.
   datediff(month, date1, date2) --> SUBTR(TO_NUMBER(date2- date1),6,7);
2. I need 'YYYYMM' value from below result, but the system shows 'ORA-00904: "MM": invalid identifier' .
   CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date1)) + format(date1, 'MM') --> TO_CHAR(i.ordr_clsd_dt,YYYY) + TO_CHAR(i.ordr_clsd_dt,MM)

`date1` and `date2` are all `date` type data.

Answer (score 1):

Check function [MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669)

When you have the number of months between two dates, then you just need some formatting. You can use numeric value of months, or convert to an `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` value

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT DATE '2020-08-01' date1, DATE '2021-11-01' date2 FROM dual),
mb AS
    (SELECT date1, date2, MONTHS_BETWEEN(date2, date1) AS MONTHSBETWEEN FROM t)
SELECT date1, date2, MONTHSBETWEEN,
    LPAD(TRUNC(MONTHSBETWEEN/12), 4, '0') || LPAD(MOD(MONTHSBETWEEN, 12), 2, '0'),
    NUMTOYMINTERVAL(MONTHSBETWEEN, 'MONTH'),
    LPAD(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NUMTOYMINTERVAL(MONTHSBETWEEN, 'MONTH')) , 4, '0') || LPAD(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NUMTOYMINTERVAL(MONTHSBETWEEN, 'MONTH')), 2, '0')
FROM mb;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can simply subtract two dates and get the difference in days.

```
select 
  dt1, dt2,
  trunc( months_between(dt2,dt1) ) mths, 
  dt2 - add_months( dt1, trunc(months_between(dt2,dt1)) ) days
from
(
    select date '2021-01-01' dt1, date '2021-03-25' dt2 from dual union all
    select date '2017-01-01' dt1, date '2021-01-01' dt2 from dual union all
    select date '2021-01-01' dt1, date '2021-01-01' dt2 from dual union all
    select date '2012-02-28' dt1, date '2021-03-01' dt2 from dual union all
    select date '2021-02-28' dt1, date '2021-03-01' dt2 from dual union all
    select date '2021-02-28' dt1, date '2021-04-01' dt2 from dual union all
    select trunc(sysdate-1)  dt1, sysdate               from dual
) sample_data

Results

DT1    DT2    MTHS    DAYS
01-JAN-21    25-MAR-21    2    24
01-JAN-17    01-JAN-21    48    0
01-JAN-21    01-JAN-21    0    0
28-FEB-12    01-MAR-21    108    1
28-FEB-21    01-MAR-21    0    1
28-FEB-21    01-APR-21    1    1
01-DEC-21    02-DEC-21    0    1.98178240740740740740740740740740740741
```

Comment: Thanks,
let me elaborate my purpose,
1) I only need month value 'MM' from below substraction.
datediff(month, date1, date2) --> SUBTR(TO_NUMBER(date2- date1),6,7);
2) I need 'YYYYMM' value from below result, but the system shows 'ORA-00904: "MM": invalid identifier' . 
CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date1)) + format(date1, 'MM') --> TO_CHAR(i.ordr_clsd_dt,YYYY) + TO_CHAR(i.ordr_clsd_dt,MM)

Comment: @steven sun updated original answer with several test cases. Apologies for the delay

Answer (score 0):

While Wernfrieds solution is much more complete and displays additional information you can get a simplified output with the following query I show below.

Note: Months_between can return a fraction. To remove the fraction I used the trunc command.

```
SELECT trunc (Months_between(To_date('2021103', 'YYYYMMDD'),
       To_date('20210401', 'YYYYMMDD')))
       num_months
FROM   dual;

NUM_MONTHS
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating with months is always something special, as months have different lengths. Let's see what SQL Server does here:

```
select datediff(month, '20210131', '20210201');
```

=> 1

SQL Server ignores that this is just one day. The days are in two different, adjacent months, so the answer is 1 month difference.

Oracle's `MONTHS_BETWEEN` on the other hand tries to calculate an exact difference in months' fractions:

```
select months_between(date '2021-02-01', date '2021-01-31') from dual;
```

=> 0.032258

If I wanted to look at the months only in Oracle, I'd use some simple calculation, e.g.:

```
select
  (extract(year from date2) * 12 + extract(month from date2)) -
  (extract(year from date1) * 12 + extract(month from date1))
from dates;
```

As to your second question: You want YYYYMM, so use the format 'YYYYMM'. The format is a string literal, hence we need single quotes. Without them Oracle would think this is supposed to be a column name. This is why Oracle tells you you are using an invalid identifier in your query, as the column `mm` does not exist.

```
TO_CHAR(i.ordr_clsd_dt, 'yyyymm')
```

Or as a numeric value:

```
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(i.ordr_clsd_dt, 'yyyymm'))
```